# Help Understanding libgdx create animations example game

Tags: libgdx, animation

I am trying to understand the example game, cuboc. GitHub is https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx-demo-cuboc. I have generated my texture atlas but I do not understand the code that uses this texture atlas.  Here's the code (you can see on github too [here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx-demo-cuboc/blob/master/core/src/com/badlogic/cubocy/MapRenderer.java):

```
package com.badlogic.cubocy;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.FPSLogger;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Animation;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteCache;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ImmediateModeRenderer20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector3;

public class MapRenderer {
...
    private void createAnimations () {
        this.tile = new TextureRegion(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/tile.png")), 0, 0, 20, 20);
        Texture bobTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/bob.png"));
        TextureRegion[] split = new TextureRegion(bobTexture).split(20, 20)[0];
        TextureRegion[] mirror = new TextureRegion(bobTexture).split(20, 20)[0];
        for (TextureRegion region : mirror)
            region.flip(true, false);
        spikes = split[5];
        bobRight = new Animation(0.1f, split[0], split[1]);
        bobLeft = new Animation(0.1f, mirror[0], mirror[1]);
        bobJumpRight = new Animation(0.1f, split[2], split[3]);
        bobJumpLeft = new Animation(0.1f, mirror[2], mirror[3]);
        bobIdleRight = new Animation(0.5f, split[0], split[4]);
        bobIdleLeft = new Animation(0.5f, mirror[0], mirror[4]);
        bobDead = new Animation(0.2f, split[0]);
        split = new TextureRegion(bobTexture).split(20, 20)[1];
        cube = split[0];
        cubeFixed = new Animation(1, split[1], split[2], split[3], split[4], split[5]);
        split = new TextureRegion(bobTexture).split(20, 20)[2];
        cubeControlled = split[0];
        spawn = new Animation(0.1f, split[4], split[3], split[2], split[1]);
        dying = new Animation(0.1f, split[1], split[2], split[3], split[4]);
        dispenser = split[5];
        split = new TextureRegion(bobTexture).split(20, 20)[3];
        rocket = new Animation(0.1f, split[0], split[1], split[2], split[3]);
        rocketPad = split[4];
        split = new TextureRegion(bobTexture).split(20, 20)[4];
        rocketExplosion = new Animation(0.1f, split[0], split[1], split[2], split[3], split[4], split[4]);
        split = new TextureRegion(bobTexture).split(20, 20)[5];
        endDoor = split[2];
        movingSpikes = split[0];
        laser = split[1];
    }
```

What I do not understand is what is `split` used for? Like, what is going on here:

```
split = new TextureRegion(bobTexture).split(20, 20)[1];
```

And sometimes it looks like `split` is a method that takes two `int`'s, `20` and `20`? Why 20?
Othertimes `split` is used as an `Array` like in ...

```
rocketExplosion = new Animation(0.1f, split[0], split[1], split[2], split[3], split[4], split[4]);
```

... and I just can't follow what's going on here.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/TextureRegion.html#split-int-int-):

> public TextureRegion[][] split(int tileWidth,
>                                  int tileHeight)
>
> Helper function to create tiles out of this TextureRegion starting
>   from the top left corner going to the right and ending at the bottom
>   right corner. Only complete tiles will be returned so if the region's
>   width or height are not a multiple of the tile width and height not
>   all of the region will be used. This will not work on texture regions
>   returned form a TextureAtlas that either have whitespace removed or
>   where flipped before the region is split.
>
> Parameters:
>
> - tileWidth - a tile's width in pixels
> - tileHeight - a tile's height in pixels
>
> Returns:
>
> a 2D array of TextureRegions indexed by [row][column].

Looks like the texture is actually a texture atlas, or tile map. The split method takes one texture and splits it into texture tiles. The image has tiles that are 20 by 20 pixels, passing `20,20` into `split` splits the image into tiles that are 20 pixels by 20 pixels.

So something like

```
TextureRegion(bobTexture).split(20, 20)[1];
```

would return the second row of tiles in the sprite sheet.

Answer (score 1):

this is easy way to create animations, you can add all animation images to one image and than use them separately , for example each image is 20x20 pixel and your animation contains 3 images so the big image will be 60x20 , and if you split it by 20 x20 pixel you can get all the images , and then put those images in animation .
Another example. your character have two animations walk right and left, walking left animation contains 2images and walking right animation again 2, so your bug image can contain 4 images (30x30)  the big image can be 120x30 or 60x60 , and by splitting this 30x30 you can get animation images separately and walking left can be 0,1 index in the array and right 2,3  .